# "This site can’t be reached" after setting domain to Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, hosting, namecheap

I have deployed my Node.js app to Heroku my app URL [meusama.herokuapp.com](https://meusama.herokuapp.com), My problem is setting up the domain name to my app.
I had bought a new domain for my app from NameCheap [meusama.dev](http://www.meusama.dev) and I set to my app but I get this error message, after two days too.

> This site can’t be reached meusama.dev took too long to respond.
>
> This site can’t be reached www.meusama.dev’s server IP address could
>   not be found.

**How do I set my domain name,**

1. **Add my domain to Heroku**

[image: Add my domain to Heroku Image]
After setting it I get the *DNS target* for *www.meusama.dev*

2. **Copied DNS target**
   [image: DNS target image]
   DNS target `comparative-lychee-mlmbgj7ycrauqqwqe30dllu4z.herokudns.com`
3. **Setup Namecheap with DNS target**

Past my DNS target which I get from Heroku to CNAME RECORD as below image.
[image]

This all what I do, Do I have missed any steps or do anything wrong.
Pleases provide me a solution to this problem thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a www to the Heroku DNS Target, that is your problem.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: Don't add a www to the Heroku DNS target.